# Creating a "Delete Item" function for a FlatList

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, this, react-native-flatlist

I have a flatList and I am trying to delete an item with a button from my flatList. I have created a function titled `deleteTask`. I am getting an error message which states "_this2.deleteTask is not a function."

I would appreciate any help. My code is below:

In TaskList.js:

```
class TaskList extends React.Component {
static navigationOptions = {
title: 'My Task List',
};
constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = {
taskList: [
new Task("Feed cat")
.setPriority(4)
.addTag("home")
.addTag("pet")
.setDeadlineRandomly(),
new Task("Buy milk")
.setPriority(2)
.addTag("errand")
.addTag("grocery")
.setDeadlineRandomly(),
new Task("Do assignment")
.setPriority(5)
.addTag("focus")
.addTag("school")
.setDeadlineRandomly(),
],
}
}

renderItem(item) {
return (
<TaskItem
key={item.item.key}
task={item.item}
editTask={(key) => this.editTask(key)}
deleteTask={(key) => this.deleteTask(key)}
/>
)
}

deleteTask(key){
console.log("TRYING TO DELETE", key)
for(var i = 0; i < this.state.taskList.length; i++) {
console.log(i, this.state.taskList[i].key)
if(this.state.taskList[i].key == key) {
// Found it
this.state.taskList.splice(i,1)
console.log("DELETING THAT ONE", this.state.taskList)
 }
 }
 this.setState({taskList: this.state.taskList})
 }
```

In TaskItem.js

```
export default class TaskItem extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {task: props.task}
}

render() {
const task = this.state.task
const due = task.relativeDeadlineString()
// These styles will be customized based on current state
let descStyle = {fontSize:20, fontWeight: 'bold'}
let dueStyle = {fontSize:18}
let priStyle = {
flexDirection: 'row',
}
if(task.isDone()) {
  descStyle.textDecorationLine = 'line-through'
  descStyle.textDecorationStyle = 'solid'
  descStyle.color = '#aaaaaa'
}
else {                      // Otherwise task is not done
  priStyle.backgroundColor = task.getPriorityColor()
}
return (
  <View style={styles.item}>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.toggleDone()}>
   <View style={styles.container}>
      {renderIf(!this.state.task.isDone(), <MaterialCommunityIcons name="checkbox-blank-outline" size={40}/>)}
      {renderIf(this.state.task.isDone(), <MaterialCommunityIcons name="checkbox-marked-outline" size={40}/>)}  
   </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
    <View style={styles.info}>
      <View style={styles.firstRow}>
      <Text style={descStyle}>{task.getDescription()}</Text>
  <View style={styles.middleRow}>
  <View style={styles.checkbox}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={()=>{task.deleteTask(task.key)}}>
        <Icon name="trash" size={24} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but your splice code is wrong - you don't want to mutate your state.

Instead, you should do const newList = this.state.taskList.slice(); newList.splice(key, 1); this.setState({taskList: newList })

Comment: So ... what was the problem?

Comment: did your issue solved?

Comment: Problem solved. I added onto another function I had named `renderItem`. In that function I specified the value of deleteTask. See updates above.

Answer (score 0):

Is `deleteTask` passed into TaskList in the `props`?

```
  <TouchableOpacity
 - onPress={()=>{this.deleteTask(task.key)}}>
 + onPress={()=>{this.props.deleteTask(task.key)}}>
  <Icon name="trash" size={24} />
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: They're using an arrow function in the render so it shouldn't be that

Comment: Gonna have to go play with that @AnilRedshift. It's in a different file though, so it probably just needs to be `props.deleteTask` instead of `this.deleteTask`.

Answer (score 0):

In TaskList.js

```
deleteTask(key){
 console.log("TRYING TO DELETE", key)
 var taskList = this.state.taskList.splice(key, 1); <-- I hope this works.
 this.setState({taskList: taskList})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
deleteTask(key){
console.log("TRYING TO DELETE", key)
for(var i = 0; i < this.state.taskList.length; i++) {
console.log(i, this.state.taskList[i].key)
if(this.state.taskList[i].key == key) {
// Found it
this.state.taskList.splice(i,1)
console.log("DELETING THAT ONE", this.state.taskList)
}
}
this.setState({taskList: this.state.taskList})
}
```